# Show Message List in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, message

I want to show the message list like facebook messenger where in left corner you can see all the message you make.

**user_table**

```
user_id
user_firstname
user_latsname
```

**message_table**

```
message_id
message_user_id
message_to_user_id
message_content
message_time_stamp
```

**My SQL**

```
SELECT user_table.user_id,
             CONCAT(user_table.user_firstname,' ',user_table.user_lastname) AS user_fullname,
             message_table.message_user_id,
             message_table.message_content,
             message_table.message_time_stamp
      FROM user_table
      INNER JOIN message_table
      ON user_table.user_id = message_table.message_user_id
      WHERE (message_table.message_to_user_id = '$session')
      ORDER BY message_table.message_time_stamp DESC
```

My code works fine if someone message me first. 
It show in my message list that someone message me. 
But when i'm the one who make the first message. 
It doesn't show in my message list.
He should reply in my message before i can see it in my message list.
But i want to show when someone message me and when i'm the one who make the first message.

[message_table with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgUNf.png)

[user_table with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqKjy.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXrDR.png)

But when i add new user in the user_table and message him. it will not show in my Message List.

I want my expected result is when i message new user it will show in my message list

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Without a schema hard to say but maybe `or message_table.message_from_user_id = 'user1'`

Comment: Manually query your database: `select message_user_id,message_time_stamp,message_content from message_table where message_user_id = <<USER1'S ID>> order by message_time_stamp desc`.  I'm pretty sure you'll see THE EXACT SAME ROWS.  Because it looks like that's the way your database is organized.

Comment: i edit my question i hope someone understand my question.

Comment: Hi paulsm4 if i change the where clause to message_user_id = user id it show my user_table data not the user_table data i'm messaging.

Comment: sample data current and expected output please

Comment: What is the `from` user id column, `message_user_id`? Some explanation to the columns would help the question

Comment: `message_user_id` is the user who send the message. the recipient is `message_to_user_id`

Comment: Post your solution as an *answer* and then, when you're able (in two days time for self-answers), accept that answer by checking the tick mark besides that answer. Please don't add 'solved' to the question title, use the system as it's designed.

Comment: okey sir sorry hehe tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT user_id, user_fullname, message_content
FROM
(
        (SELECT user_table.user_id,
                 CONCAT(user_table.user_firstname,' ',user_table.user_lastname) AS user_fullname,
                 message_table.message_user_id,
                 message_table.message_content,
                 message_table.message_time_stamp
          FROM user_table
          INNER JOIN message_table
          ON user_table.user_id = message_table.message_to_user_id
          WHERE (message_table.message_user_id = '$session')

        )ORDER BY message_time_stamp DESC

UNION DISTINCT

        (SELECT user_table.user_id,
                 CONCAT(user_table.user_firstname,' ',user_table.user_lastname) AS user_fullname,
                 message_table.message_user_id,
                 message_table.message_content,
                 message_table.message_time_stamp
          FROM user_table
          INNER JOIN message_table
          ON user_table.user_id = message_table.message_user_id
          WHERE (message_table.message_to_user_id = '$session')

         )ORDER BY message_time_stamp DESC

) as id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY message_time_stamp DESC
```

Here's the solution what i made in my problem. I made 2 select statement where the first select only select where i'm the one who makes the first message and the second select statements select where someone first message me. And then i Union it.

Answer (score 0):

your line (in sql query)

```
message_table.message_to_user_id = '$session'
```

is probably the reason, why you don't see the messages you send yourself (since you are not the recipient)

to fetch all messages you're involved in, it should probably be:

```
message_table.message_to_user_id = '$session' or message_table.message_user_id = '$session'
```

I hope $session is not user-provided, or you've got some possible sql-injection at hand ;o)

Comment: my $session is base on the user_id of user. is there any bad there? need advice

Comment: if the user_id has to adhere to a very strict scheme (especially no `'` chars allowed), you *should* be fine.